# How to convert GMT time to EST time using Python

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I want convert GMT time to EST time and get a timestamp. I tried the following but don't know how to set time zone.

```
time = "Tue, 12 Jun 2012 14:03:10 GMT"
timestamp2 = time.mktime(time.strptime(time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT'))
```

Comment: There's no way that the code you posted runs at all, since you named a string `time` and then tried to use a function from the `time` package which is no longer accessible at that name.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Time zones aren't built into standard Python - you need to use another library. [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) is a good choice.

```
>>> gmt = pytz.timezone('GMT')
>>> eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
>>> time = "Tue, 12 Jun 2012 14:03:10 GMT"
>>> date = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
>>> date
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 12, 14, 3, 10)
>>> dategmt = gmt.localize(date)
>>> dategmt
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 12, 14, 3, 10, tzinfo=<StaticTzInfo 'GMT'>)
>>> dateeastern = dategmt.astimezone(eastern)
>>> dateeastern
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 12, 10, 3, 10, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

Answer (score 14):

Using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"
now_time = datetime.now(timezone('US/Eastern'))
print now_time.strftime(fmt)
```

Answer (score 11):

With **Python 3.9**, time zone handling is built into the standard lib with the [**zoneinfo**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) module (for older Python versions, use `zoneinfo` via [backports.zoneinfo](https://github.com/pganssle/zoneinfo)).

***Ex:***

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from datetime import datetime, timezone

time = "Tue, 12 Jun 2012 14:03:10 GMT"

# parse to datetime, using %Z for the time zone abbreviation
dtobj = datetime.strptime(time, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z')

# note that "GMT" (=UTC) is ignored:
# datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 12, 14, 3, 10)

# ...so let's correct that:
dtobj = dtobj.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
# datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 12, 14, 3, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

# convert to US/Eastern (EST or EDT, depending on time of the year)
dtobj = dtobj.astimezone(ZoneInfo('US/Eastern'))
# datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 12, 10, 3, 10, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Eastern'))
print(dtobj)
# 2012-06-12 10:03:10-04:00
```

---

And there's also [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which follows the same semantics:

```
import dateutil
# no strptime needed...
# correctly localizes to GMT (=UTC) directly
dtobj = dateutil.parser.parse(time) 

dtobj = dtobj.astimezone(dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Eastern'))
# datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 12, 10, 3, 10, tzinfo=tzfile('US/Eastern'))
print(dtobj)
# 2012-06-12 10:03:10-04:00
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `backports.zoneinfo`, because of my choice of OS I'm stuck at Python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

If it is your local timezone and the timezone rules are the same for the given time as they are now then you could use stdlib-only solution (except for some edge cases):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz("Tue, 12 Jun 2012 14:03:10 GMT"))
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp))
# -> 2012-06-12 10:03:10
```

Otherwise you need data from a historical timezone database to get the correct utc offset. [`pytz` module](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) provides access to [the tz database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

timestamp = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz("Tue, 12 Jun 2012 14:03:10 GMT"))
eastern_dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
print(eastern_dt.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)'))
# -> Tue, 12 Jun 2012 10:03:10 -0400 (EDT)
```

Note: POSIX `timestamp`  is the same around the world i.e., your local timezone doesn't matter if you want to find the timestamp (unless your timezone is of "right" kind). Here's how to [convert a utc time to the timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).